# What should I do with a crappy approved edit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I've just reviewed [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8728223) and I see it was approved. I left a comment there so that other reviewers would see it. The edit is clearly fixing issues with the posted code, which could potentially fix the OP's problem.

The edit got approved either way... what's the recommended action for me once I see something like this? should I go ahead and edit the question back to what it was? should I just forget about it?

The question isn't extremely good either, but I'm more interested in how to resolve the situation in the future than in this particular case.

Comment: Definitely a case for a rollback. Code changes (not matter how minimal) should not be left up to editors.

Comment: Note: if you vote for an "other" rejection, the other reviewers won't see your message until they vote. They can only see that a person voted for "reject other", not what it said.

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks! that's good to know

Comment: To be fair, when I looked at that edit, I first saw the title and body corrections, not the code edits. Ignoring the code edits, the edit at least tried to clean up the mess that was the title. The code edits were probably overstepping things, but I don't think the rest of the edit was horrible. I've certainly seen a lot worse edits be approved.

Comment: @BradLarson isn't the code the most important part of the question on "why doesn't this code do X" questions? these kind of edits would potentially make ok answers become unrelated to the question

Comment: I'm not arguing that the code edit was appropriate, just that everything else around it wasn't terrible. It at least tried to fix some pretty bad issues with the question. I was pointing out how even good reviewers could have missed the more subtle code changes and approved that edit. The whole edit didn't need to be rolled back, just the code changes.

Comment: Eh, that code edit looks absolutely fine to me, frankly. I would have approved this edit with a smile. The user's history looks fine too, @Trobbins. Honestly not getting what all the fuss is about here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit really??? OP posted `print(2.Subtract')` which is wrong (missing a leading apostrophe). The editor changed it to `print('2.Subtract')`. Fixing OP's error in an edit seems atrocious to me.

Comment: @GervasioMarchand: Oh, I see, it's a _question_.. hmm.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Roll back the edit.  If the non-code changes are fine then you could just roll back the code changes.

Given that this case is particularly egregious, with such edits to the code in a question, you could consider flagging the post for moderator attention as those reviewers might need a timeout.

Comment: Looking at the particular user's suggestion history, it looks like a timeout may be well deserved.

Comment: Going for a Close, OT typo, on the question on SO.

Comment: @Trobbins: Why's that then? The suggestion history looks fine to me. Good, even.

Comment: How is that OT:Typo?  Read the accepted answer.  The problem was the order of `return` and `print` statements, not the typo, according to that  (which may or may not have been in the actual code).